# Anchor tag of Struts2 is not invoking a Struts2 action

Tags: jsp, struts2

In the jsp that will follow, there are 2 ways of activating the login and register actions: 2 submit's and 2 a's. The submits work fine, but when I need to integrate with a css Framework, I'll need the anchors. But they are not working, thought I think they are properly configured.

My Jsp is:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"> 
        <title>MeeTO</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <s:form action="loginAction" method="post" >
            <s:url var="loginLink" action="loginAction.action" />
            <s:url var="registerLink" action="registerAction.action" />

            <s:label cssClass="login" value="Please fill in the form below in order to Register or Log in:" /> <br>

            <s:label for="userBean.username" value="Username:"/> 
            <s:textfield name="userBean.username" /> <br>

            <s:label for="userBean.password"  value="Password:"/> 
            <s:password name="userBean.password" /> <br>

            <s:a href="%{loginLink}">
                LogIn
            </s:a> <br>
            <s:a href="%{registerLink}">
                Register
            </s:a> <br>

            <s:submit value="LogIn" action="loginAction" /> <br>
            <s:submit value="Register" action="registerAction" /> <br>
        </s:form>

        <s:fielderror/>
        <s:actionerror/>
        <s:actionmessage/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: may be you can try this `<s:a href='#' onCliclk="%{registerLink}">  Register </s:a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pravin thank you for your cooperation. I changed this:

```
<s:url var="loginLink" action="loginAction.action" />
<s:url var="registerLink" action="registerAction.action" />
```

to:

```
<s:url var="loginLink" action="loginAction" />
<s:url var="registerLink" action="registerAction" />
```

and it works fine now. Apperantly it's not needed to force the action.

Comment: Exactly. Action extension must be omitted and namespace must be specified (if any)